# How to automatically load data from json file on startup with kivy

Tags: android, python, json, load, kivy

I am making an android app with python and kivy that keeps track of diabetes entries and has a basic profile page. I figured out how to save input from textinput widgets into a json file which works fine.  However I cannot figure out how to automatically load this information back into the textinput widets on the startup.  Loading into the labels could work too but it would be sloppier. I know there is an on_start module, but I have no idea how to use it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

.kv file

```
<Phone>:
result: _result
h: _h
w: _w
n: name_input
g: gender_input
t: _type
ti: _times
m: _meds





AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'top'

    ScreenManager:
        size_hint: 1, .9
        id: _screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: 'home'
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    source: "/home/aaron/Desktop/main.png"
            Label:
                markup: True
                text: '[size=100][color=ff3333]Welcome to [color=ff3333]Diabetes Manager[/color][/size]'
        Screen:
            name: 'menu'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 2
                padding: 50
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        source: "/home/aaron/Desktop/main.png"

                Button:
                    text: 'My Profile'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'profile' 
                Button:
                    text: 'History'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'history'     

                Button:
                    text: 'New Entry'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'new_entry' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Graph'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'graph' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Diet'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'diet' 
                Button:
                    text: 'Settings'
                    on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'settings' 

        Screen:
            name: 'profile'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 1
                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Name[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: name_input
                        hint_text: 'Name'
                    Button:
                        size_hint_x: 0.15
                        text: 'Load'
                        on_press: root.load()



                BoxLayout:
                    Label:  
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Gender[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: gender_input
                        hint_text: 'Gender'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=34][color=0000ff]Type of Diabetes[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _type
                        hint_text: 'Type of Diabetes'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Height (in)[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _h
                        hint_text: 'Height in inches'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Weight (lb)[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _w
                        hint_text: 'Weight in pounds'

                BoxLayout:
                    Button:
                        text: 'Calculate BMI'
                        on_press: root.product(*args)

                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 4.5
                        id:_result
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]BMI[/color][/size]'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=30][color=0000ff]List of Medications[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _meds
                        hint_text: 'List of Medications'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=38][color=0000ff]Insulin Times[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _times
                        hint_text: 'Please Enter Times to Take Insulin'

                    Button:
                        size_hint_x: 0.15
                        text: 'Done'
                        on_press: root.save()


        Screen:
            name: 'history'
            GridLayout: 
                cols:1

        Screen:
            name: 'new_entry'
            GridLayout:
                cols:1

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Time[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _time
                        hint_text: 'Current Time'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=28][color=0000ff]Blood Sugar (mg/dL)[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _glucose_reading
                        hint_text: 'Current Blood Sugar'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=40][color=0000ff]Carbs[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _food
                        hint_text: 'Total Carbs for meal'

                BoxLayout:
                    Label:
                        size_hint_x: 0.22
                        bold: True
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=30][color=0000ff]Medications Taken[/color][/size]'
                    TextInput:
                        id: _meds_taken
                        hint_text: 'Please Enter Any Medications Taken'


        Screen:
            name: 'graph'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Your Graph[/color][/size]'

        Screen:
            name: 'diet'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Reccomended Diet[/color][/size]'


        Screen:
            name: 'settings'
            GridLayout: 
                cols: 3
                padding: 50
            Label: 
                markup: True
                text: '[size=24][color=dd88ff]Settings[/color][/size]'


AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'bottom'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1, .1
        Button:
            id: btnExit
            text: 'Exit'
            on_press: app.save(_name.text, gender.txt)
        Button:
            text: 'Menu'
            on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'menu'
```

.py

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty
    from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
    from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
    from os.path import join
    from os.path import exists
    from kivy.compat import iteritems
    from kivy.storage import AbstractStore
    from json import loads, dump
    from kivy.config import Config



class Phone(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # make sure we aren't overriding any important functionality
        super(Phone, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    with self.canvas.before:
        Color(0, 1, 0, 1)  # green; colors range from 0-1 instead of 0-255
        self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

    self.bind(size=self._update_rect, pos=self._update_rect)

def _update_rect(self, instance, value):
    self.rect.pos = instance.pos
    self.rect.size = instance.size

def product(self, instance):
    self.result.text = str(float(self.w.text) * 703/ (float(self.h.text) * float(self.h.text)))

def save(self):
    store = JsonStore('hello.json')
    name = self.n.text
    gender = self.g.text
    dtype = self.t.text
    height = self.h.text
    weight = self.w.text
    medications = self.m.text
    store.put('profile', name=name, gender=gender, dtpe=dtype, height=height, weight=weight, medications=medications)


presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class PhoneApp(App):
    def build(self):
        store = JsonStore('hello.json')

        return Phone()



if __name__ == '__main__':
   PhoneApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do the reverse of what you're already doing in `save()`. For example:

```
def load(self):
    store = JsonStore('hello.json')
    profile = store.get('profile')
    self.n.text = profile['name']
    self.g.text = profile['gender']
    ...
```

Then just call that method somewhere, like in `__init__()`.

Comment: Thanks this works great when i tested it with a loading button, but how would I recursively call this in the phone class?

Comment: Everything works fine when I have some information in the json file, but if i delete the information in the json file then it crashes on startup

Comment: Then you should define defaults: `self.n.text = profile.get('name', 'default name')`